# How to make this simple expression $f(\dfrac{r}{h})$ look nice?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

How to make this very simple expression nice?

[image]

I am not convinced by the parenthesis and the vertical spaces among the fraction. Feel free to share how you would have written it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation*}
f\big(\,\dfrac{r}{h}\,\big)\quad f\Big(\,\dfrac{r}{h}\,\Big) \quad f\left(\,\dfrac{r}{h}\,\right) \quad f\big(\,\cfrac{r}{h}\,\big)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `\biggl (` and `biggr )` ...

Comment: @juanuni Well, it makes the parenthesis larger, but that's not beautiful either...

Comment: Beatiful concept is subjetive ...

Comment: According to me, the following is the correct version: `f\Bigl(\frac{r}{h}\Bigr)`. No need to add extra horizontal space with `\,`.

Comment: @understood Per ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf for in-line text usage  `f(r/h)` is preferred and for display either the previous form or use one of  `f\mleft(\frac{r}{h}\mright)` or `f(\tfrac{r}{h})`.  The priority guideline for choice is clarity for the reader and not beauty.

Comment: WIthout knowing the specific context in wihich you intend to use the fractions, I would probably go with either `f(r/h)` or `f(\tfrac{r}{h})`.

Comment: the main reason it looks odd is that you are using the display fraction in inline math so generating excessive space, why not `\frac` rather than `\dfrac`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The additional spaces look odd to me. I would not add spaces in the inside. The spaces by `\left` and `\right` can be removed by using `\mleft` and `\mright` of package `mleftright`.

Depending on the remaining part of the equation or the other equations,
`\tfrac` might be an option. Then the parentheses do not need to be enlarged.

Also the slash variant for the division can be used here instead of the fraction. You have loaded package `nicefrac`. The following example also shows the `\nicefrac` version:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{equation*}
  f\mleft(\frac{r}{h}\mright) = f(\tfrac{r}{h})
  = f(r/h) = f(\nicefrac{r}{h})
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course the placement of the numerator can also be "optimized" by hand
using `\raisebox` to lower the numerator. But, IMHO, it only optimizes the lookout of one combination of symbols. Symbols with descenders or subscripts will then have different base lines, which look worse:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}
\[
   f\mleft( \frac{\raisebox{-2pt}{$r$}}{h} \mright) \neq
   f\mleft( \frac{\raisebox{-2pt}{$g$}}{h} \mright) \neq
   f\mleft( \frac{\raisebox{-2pt}{$r_g$}}{h} \mright)
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

IMHO, the reader will benefit much more, when the available time is used more to improve the mathematics and their explanation in the text.

Comment: But don't you find it strange that the space between the $r$ and the fraction bar is larger than the one between $h$ and the fraction bar, in the left-hand side? I suppose the bar is in the middle of the upper and lower baseline though... But still I'm not convinced.

Comment: @anderstood This is the "displayed" version of the fraction without decreased size and more vertical space (for indices, ...). Also `r` is a small letter, With `\vphantom{h}`, the parentheses would probably look more symmetrical, but would also be larger.

Comment: Maybe you can controle the vertical space with `\smash` command.

Comment: Per ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf for in-line text usage  `f(r/h)` is preferred and for display either the previous form or use one of  `f\mleft(\frac{r}{h}\mright)` or `f(\tfrac{r}{h})`.  The priority guideline for choice is clarity for the reader and not beauty.

Comment: @R.Schumacher Concerning the last sentence: sure, but I consider all the suggestions as equality clear. Anyway, you all agree on that point: keep the default vertical space when using $\frac$ or its variants.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I adopt is usually to use `\mfrac` (medium-sized fractions, ~80% of displaystyle), from `nccmath`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\verb+With \dfrac:+\enspace Text text text text text text $f\Bigl(\dfrac{r}{h}\Bigr)$ more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text…\medskip

\verb+With \mfrac:+\enspace Text text text text text text $f\bigl(\mfrac{r}{h}\bigr)$ more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text…\medskip

\verb+With \frac:+\enspace Text text text text text text $f(\frac{r}{h})$ more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text…
\end{document}
```

[image]